# java.exe in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" overridden local Java installation

Tags: java, windows-10, environment-variables

Why and how come `java.exe` appeared in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe", on Windows 10, and even more surprisingly - overridden my OpenJDK's `java.exe` binary, out of a sudden, which I have as an explicit System Variable, in the environment variables?

Just got some awkward behaviour, after which, decided to check `where java`, which got me this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
my actual OpenJDK 11 distribution\binaries
```

And it happened on its own.

What is this?

**Update:**

I have found it in the PATH system variable and just removed. I hope Windows OS won't start to misbehave due to this.. but I still wonder HOW this got there and HOW it has overridden my local Java installation.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently that "...\javapath..." entry is prepended to the PATH by the Oracle Java installer in Java 8.  It is also possible that later Oracle Java installers do this too.

Source: https://douglascayers.com/2015/05/30/how-to-set-custom-java-path-after-installing-jdk-8/

> And it happened on its own.

This shouldn't happen spontaneously.  I posit that you actually ran an Oracle Java installer, or possibly some other installer that had an embedded Java installer.

> I have found it in the PATH system variable and just removed. I hope Windows OS won't start to misbehave due to this

Windows *per se* doesn't depend on Java.  You won't break Windows.

It is *possible* that some 3rd-party software that you installed might break; e.g. if that software specifically requires a different version of Java to the Java 11 which what is current on your PATH.

However, if it does you can always undo the change.  (I wouldn't worry about this.)